# Image swapping With different

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am very new to JQuery and seem to understand better in worked examples. I want to make a system where you can customise furniture. I have the image swapping part of the code but it limits me to one option per page. Is there any way i can hide a drop down list acording to what they have picked on the first box.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select onchange="$('#imageToSwap').attr('src', this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
    <option value="https://www.humanscale.com/ImagesConfig/S111BM10W101------_2_212x336.png" selected>With arm rests</option>
    <option value="https://www.humanscale.com/ImagesConfig/S110BM10W101------_2_212x336.png">Arm Less</option>
</select>
<img id="imageToSwap" class="profile" src="https://www.humanscale.com/ImagesConfig/S111BM10W101------_2_212x336.png">
```

That is the first box that changes the picture. This code should change the colour of chairs with arms and does.

But the other drop down box for armless can overide what that image is.

Below is armless code

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select onchange="$('#imageToSwap').attr('src', this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
  <option value="https://www.humanscale.com/ImagesConfig/S110BM10W101------_2_212x336.png" selected>Black</option>
  <option value="https://www.humanscale.com/ImagesConfig/S110BM10W507------_2_212x336.png">Navy</option>
  <option value="https://www.humanscale.com/ImagesConfig/S110BM10W415------_2_212x336.png">Sage</option>
</select>
```

Any way i want one drop down to be displayed if arm rests are selected and one if arm rests are not. Not both of them at the same time.

All help will be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: You are changing the `src` of `$('#imageToSwap')` in both cases. If you want the second drop-down to change another image, change that selector - `#imageToSwap`

Comment: Your images seem to have disappeared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is choose whether you want to show the armrests or not by selecting a radio button and then show a set of selects (coloured with armrests/coloured + armless) depending on what the radio value is.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var base = "";
  var checkedVal = $("#chair").find("input[name=arms]:checked").val();
  $("input[type='radio']").change(function() {
    var sel = $("input[name='arms']:checked").val();

    base = "https://www.humanscale.com/ImagesConfig";
    var baseext = "";
    if (sel == "1") {
      baseext = "/S111";
    } else {
      baseext = "/S110";
    }
    
    $('#colours option').remove()
    $("#colours").append('<option value=' + base + baseext + 'BM10W101------_2_212x336.png">Black</option>')
    $("#colours").append('<option value=' + base + baseext + 'BM10W507------_2_212x336.png">Navy</option>')
    $("#colours").append('<option value=' + base + baseext + 'BM10W415------_2_212x336.png">Sage</option>')
    });
  
});
```

```css
input {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

select {
  vertical-align: top;
}

#imageToSwap{
display:block;
margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="chair">
  <input type="radio" name="arms" value="1" checked> With Armrests<br>
  <input type="radio" name="arms" value="2"> Armless
</form>
<br>


<select id="colours" onchange="$('#imageToSwap').attr('src', this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
</select>


<img id="imageToSwap" class="profile" src="https://www.humanscale.com/ImagesConfig/S111BM10W101------_2_212x336.png">
```

Good luck with it!

Comment: No probs :) Happy to help!